# I can't scrape with beautifulsoup a certain list of <li class>

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, jupyter-lab

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.uplannerperu.com/shop/').text
#print(html_text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
archive = soup.find('div', class_ = 'archive-products')
#print(archive)
ulproducts = archive.find_all('ul')
#print(ulproducts)
productname = ulproducts.find()
print(productname)```


This is my print for error code, and somewhere between the begining of the list and the start of the <li class> is something I don't know that is cracking up.
````

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
9 ulproducts = archive.find_all('ul')
10 #print(ulproducts)
---> 11 productname = ulproducts.find('a', href_ = 'https://www.uplannerperu.com/product/botanical-nights-2022/' class="ansi-yellow-intense-fg ansi-bold">)
12 print(productname)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in **getattr**(self, key)
2171     def **getattr**(self, key):
2172         """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
-> 2173         raise AttributeError(
2174             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
2175         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```

I'm trying to scrape all of the products at once, but i Had this parse problem with the HTML Code.

Answer (score 1):

In the penultimate line you are not passing anything to the find() method, and by using `ulproducts = archive.find_all('ul')`, you are getting an array

```
productname = ulproducts.find()
```